# TabLayoutPanel disable a Tab GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-tablayoutpanel

How can i disable a tab (i.e the user cannot open the tab when he clicks on it) in the TabLayoutPanel?I searched online but was not able to find a solution

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [`BeforeSelectionHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html#addBeforeSelectionHandler(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.BeforeSelectionHandler)):

```
TabLayoutPanel myPanel = new TabLayoutPanel();
// Add children...

myPanel.addBeforeSelectionHandler(new BeforeSelectionHandler<Integer>() {
  @Override
  public void onBeforeSelection(BeforeSelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
    // Simple if statement - your test for whether the tab should be disabled
    // will probably be more complicated
    if (event.getItem() == 1) {
      // Canceling the event prevents the tab from being selected.
      event.cancel();
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to style the disabled tab differently than enabled tabs, you can use [`TabLayoutPanel#getTabWidget`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html#getTabWidget(int)) to get the tab widget and add a style name to it.

Comment: how do i enable it back again?

Comment: Only call event.cancel() in the BeforeSelectionHandler when you want the tab to be disabled.

Comment: the requirement i have is that i need the tab to disable when the page which has the tab loads first time.But when something happens, i need to enable the tab again.How can i achieve this?

Comment: In the if statement in onBeforeSelection() test whether the tab should be disabled or not based on your application state.

Comment: Yes,i have an if statement which disables the tab when the application loads.But after the application loads i need to enable the tab ,so i definitely need to change its state from disabled to enabled.

Comment: I got the solution.I just need to remove the handler in order to enable the Tab back .Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who comes across this later:

As of GWT version 1.6, disabling/enabling tabs is built into GWT. 
The `TabBar` class has a method `setTabEnabled(int index, boolean enabled)` that enables/disables the tab at a given index.

For example, to disable all the tabs in a TabPanel:

```
TabPanel myTabPanel = new TabPanel();
// Add children

TabBar tabBar = myTabPanel.getTabBar();
for(int i=0; i<tabBar.getTabCount(); i++) {
    tabBar.setTabEnabled(i, false);
}
```

See the [GWT javadoc](https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabBar.html#setTabEnabled%28int,%20boolean%29) for more info.

To style disabled tabs differently (which GWT does automatically, but if you wanted to change the style): disabled `tabBarItem` divs are given another CSS class: `gwt-TabBarItem-disabled`.

Comment: The question was about the `TabLayoutPanel` type, not `TabBar`.

Comment: @JasonTerk The `TabLayoutPanel` contains a `TabBar`! That is the part at the top of the `TabLayoutPanel` that holds the tabs. You can access the `TabBar` of a `TabLayoutPanel` by using `myTabLayoutPanel.getTabBar()` (see my answer). I've updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: There is no `getTabBar` method on the [`TabLayoutPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html) type. Perhaps you mean [`TabPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html)?

Comment: @JasonTerk Oh yeah - oops, sorry! You're right - I do mean `TabPanel`. I've corrected my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can access tab style by casting class `Tab` to `Widget`

```
TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();
((Widget)tabPanel().getTabBar().getTab(tabsToDisable.iterator().next())).addStyleName("disabled");
```